# RXJS concat: Does it execute already completed observables when another observable in the pipe executes again?

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, observable, concatenation

I have 2 observable: `initialLessons$` and `searchLessons$`.
The initialLessons$ displays a completed http fetch request of courses initially.
The searchLessons$ request is an observable `fromEvent` that listens on button click `keyup` event and executes after a button click on the search filter button (with a filter parameter).

Now, if I have `this.lessons$ = concat(initialLessons$, searchlessons$)`, normally, the operator concat from rxjs first executes the first observable, then waits for it to complete, before executing the second observable.

If I have already completed the first observable on initial request, does it "skip" the completed observable and execute the second observable only, e.g if I launch a search request on button click? Or will it again execute the first observable in the pipe and then the others sequentially? Because that would be a waste of ressources...

And same, if I only e.g execute the first observable, and the second has already completed (or is unnecessary to execute), will it still execute the second (and all others in the parameter list)?

Comment: Please find another [example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-cxsipc?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have already completed the first observable on initial request, does it "skip" the completed observable and execute the second observable only, e.g if I launch a search request on button click? Or will it again execute the first observable in the pipe and then the others sequentially? Because that would be a waste of ressources...

Yes, it does "skip" the completed observable(s). Concat works like you mentioned, concat will subscribe to the-i if and only if i-1 observable is completed. So now every time click a button, lesson$ will emit the event.

> And same, if I only e.g execute the first observable, and the second has already completed (or is unnecessary to execute), will it still execute the second (and all others in the parameter list)?

This question does not make sense (not in an offending way by the way), because if the i observable never completed, how the i+1 already completed? The keyword here is concat WILL SUBSCRIBE to every parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I've just built this very simple sample on codepen.io and it re-executes the completed observable:

```js
const first = of(1,2)
first.subscribe()
const second = of(3,4)

concat(first, second).subscribe(console.log) // Prints 1,2,3,4
```

What you could do to avoid re-executing the request would be to "cache" emissions from the first observable  by using `shareReplay(1)` which would maintain in-memory the last emission of the piped observable:

```js
const first = of(1,2).pipe(
  shareReplay(1)
)
first.subscribe()
const second = of(3,4)

concat(first, second).subscribe(console.log) // Prints 2,3,4
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you may want to look at `shareReplay` operator.

If I understand the problem right, this could be a possible approach

First you create a new Observable for fetch with shareReplay

```
const initialLessonsShareReplay$ = initialLessons$.pipe(
   // shareReplay tells to repeat the last value notified (if available)
   // when the Observable returned by the pipe is subscribed
   shareReplay(1),
   // we take 1 just to make sure that the Observable is completed
   take(1)
)
```

Now you subscribe this initialLessonsShareReplay$ in the initial request and wait for it to notify something.

When it comes the time to use the `concat` function, you will have something like this

```
concat(initialLessonsShareReplay$, searchLessons$)
```

If `initialLessonsShareReplay$` has already notified a value, then this value will be immediately notified as soon as the Observable returned by `concat` is subscribed and therefore you will have only to wait for `searchLessons$` to notify.

A similar approach can be used to manage the case where `searchLessons$` has already notified something.